# Golang - How to remove a row from a matrix?

Tags: go, 2d, slice

So I have this 2D slice, for example:

```
s := [][]int{
    {0, 1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6, 7},
    {8, 9, 10, 11},
}

fmt.Println(s)

//Outputs: [[0 1 2 3] [4 5 6 7] [8 9 10 11]]
```

How can I remove a full row from this 2D slice, so that the result would look like this if I decide to remove the middle row:

```
[[0 1 2 3] [8 9 10 11]]
```

Comment: `s = append(s[:1], s[2:]...)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GoLang: How to delete an element from a 2D slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102704/golang-how-to-delete-an-element-from-a-2d-slice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula to delete row at index `i` is:

```
s = append(s[:i], s[i+1:])
```

Here's a working example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := [][]int{
        {0, 1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6, 7}, // This will be removed.
        {8, 9, 10, 11},
    }

    // Delete row at index 1 without modifying original slice by
    // appending to a new slice.
    s2 := append([][]int{}, append(s[:1], s[2:]...)...)
    fmt.Println(s2)

    // Delete row at index 1. Original slice is modified.
    s = append(s[:1], s[2:]...)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

[Try it in the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6ZmrmwJ32cY).

I recommend you to read [Go Slice Tricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks). Some of the tricks can be applied to multidimensional slices as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
i := 1
s = append(s[:i],s[i+1:]...)
```

You can try the working code in the  [Golang playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GAXbDxKdjrg)

Another alternative way is to use the following:

```
i := 1
s = s[:i+copy(s[i:], s[i+1:])]
```

[Golang Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CMdcXf4g07Y)